# View image through another file

Tags: css, image

I'm trying to view an image from another file using CSS but the image won't show even if the address is correct. I don't have any more ideas about how I can fix this issue. Can you see what the problem is?

[Demo @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edgren/m53ab/)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The actual url for that image is this http://edgren.myftp.org:8081/gallery/images/photos/previews/P1210545.JPG

Your url returns a html page, so that's the problem

Comment: Yea. But I want to secure the image a little bit more with an external file. Therefore `photo-protection.php`.

Comment: @ErikEdgren what does that mean, "you want to secure it a little"?

Comment: PHP files can return JPEGs as well as HTML. You need to set the appropriate MIME type and then return binary data, rather than the text of an HTML file. That way, you can still perform whatever server-side processing you need to, but you *don't* have to return HTML

Comment: @ErikEdgren: That's all well and good, but that file needs to return a binary image. Keep in mind. The only "image security" on the web is a watermark.

Comment: Well background-image only knows how to interpret a direct link to your image, otherwise you'll have to put it inside your DOM, using `<img>` tag

Comment: It means that you can always - no matter what - save an image from a website. I have anti-right click in jQuery to protect my image from right click-downloads but I want to secure the image a little bit more through a file and in this file encrypt the source to the image.

Comment: @ErikEdgren you'll never be bulletproof for that matter, there's always the option of print screen

Comment: @Caelea Very true but some people don't know that print screening even exists :)

Comment: If the image can be displayed in a browser it can be downloaded. There is no way around that.

Comment: Another idea: Compose your image from let's say 9 smaller images, like a puzzle, or even more.

Comment: @Caelea That idea was just brilliant! Many thanks! :D I accept your answer to show that this issue has been solved but in another way.

Answer (score 0):

See here.

http://jsfiddle.net/m53ab/2/

```
<div style="background-color: #eaeaea; background-image: url(http://edgren.myftp.org:8081/gallery/images/photos/previews/P1210545.JPG); border: 2px solid #d1d1d1; height: 164px; width: 245px;"></div>​
```